# How to add two dataframe columns of city and state names to form single city-state column for geocoding in R?

Tags: r, attribute-joins, data-frame, combine

I tried to search for an answer to this, but I couldn't seem to find the right search terms, so I decided to spell it out quite explicitly.

I have a data frame with separate columns for cities, states, and other related data. I would like to join/combine the cities and states columns to form a new column where both the city and the state are named together so that I can properly geocode it with the `ggmap::geocode` tool. (From my understanding, you need to have the full "address" for a place in order to input it into the geocode tool...please let me know if this is incorrect.)

To illustrate, here's a mock-up of what I have:

```
city <- c("Lexington", "Cincinnati", "Indianapolis")
state <- c("Kentucky", "Ohio", "Indiana")
df <- data.frame(city, state)

> df
          city    state
1    Lexington Kentucky
2   Cincinnati     Ohio
3 Indianapolis  Indiana
```

Here's what I need:

```
> df
          city    state              address
1    Lexington Kentucky   Lexington Kentucky
2   Cincinnati     Ohio      Cincinnati Ohio
3 Indianapolis  Indiana Indianapolis Indiana
```

So how do I combine my city and state columns to form a new address column (composed of city + state in the same column)? Seems like it should be simple, but I've tried quite a few different proposed solutions to no avail.

Comment: This question seems to be about table processing in R prior to a GIS operation, but it does not seem to have a GIS component itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of many ways could be

```
df$address <- with(df, paste(city, state))
df
#           city    state              address
# 1    Lexington Kentucky   Lexington Kentucky
# 2   Cincinnati     Ohio      Cincinnati Ohio
# 3 Indianapolis  Indiana Indianapolis Indiana
```

Or `paste(df$city, df$state)` instead of `with(...)`.

> you need to have the full "address" for a place in order to input it
>   into the geocode tool.

The more precise the input, the better the output. However, from my experience the Google API is quite "clever".

Comment: Thank you! I remember when I first started learning R, `paste` was never really explained, so I wasn't sure how it was used. Thanks for the simple and clear answer!

Answer (score 2):

if you need a separating character like a space or symbol (eg., Lexington - Kentucky ) you can use "paste" assigning the "sep" argument a value, otherwise "paste0" will join the strings with no seperator.

```
df <- data.frame(city = c("Lexington", "Cincinnati", "Indianapolis"),
                 state = c("Kentucky", "Ohio", "Indiana"))

( df <- data.frame(df, address = paste(df[,"city"],df[,"state"], sep=" ")) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Not extremely efficient, but gets the job done

```
city <- c("Lexington", "Cincinnati", "Indianapolis")
state <- c("Kentucky", "Ohio", "Indiana")
df <- data.frame(city, state)

df[,3] <- cbind(paste(df[,"city" ], df[,"state"], sep=" "))
colnames(df[,3]) <- "address"

> df
      city    state              address
1    Lexington Kentucky   Lexington Kentucky
2   Cincinnati     Ohio      Cincinnati Ohio
3 Indianapolis  Indiana Indianapolis Indiana
```

Comment: Not sure why you are using cbind and paste. Be careful here, using cbind can inadvertently coerce your data.frame to a matrix. You also have the overhead of "behind the scenes" matrix coercion before the data.frame operator. A good read is the R Inferno that provides valuable insight into functions that use coercion and vector recycling. Take a look at the resulting class of: class(cbind(c(1,2,3), c(1,2,3)))